# Which is the correct way to add Typescript typings to a .NET Core project?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, npm-install, typescript-typings

I've read Q/As but still confused the whys and hows. I would like to have a managable correct method to add typescript typings to my ASP NET Core 3 (preview 5) web application when adding a javascript library

I've installed npm, followed the github readme of DefinitelyTyped:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

but this created a ./node_modules/@types/jquery/ folder relative to the current folder. (I would be a liar stating I understood how this knew I wanted the typings and not jQuery itself)

**Question**

What are the simple instructions to add/remove typings with a package manager **and** where is the correct place of them **and** how to configure the IDE build and intellisense to find them...